# How do I stop my script from timing out when I try to extract data from Google Search Console to BigQuery?

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-search-console

I'm trying to export data from Google Search Console to Big Query using Python. However it keeps timing out and I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/markleach/Python/GSC_BQ/gsc_bq.py", line 147, in <module>
    y = get_sc_df(p,"2021-12-01","2022-12-01",x)
  File "/Users/markleach/Python/GSC_BQ/gsc_bq.py", line 71, in get_sc_df
    response = service.searchanalytics().query(siteUrl=site_url, body=request).execute()
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 222, in _retry_request
    raise exception
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 218, in request
    response, content = self.http.request(
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1720, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1440, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1392, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1377, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 320, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 281, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1242, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/Users/markleach/opt/anaconda3/envs/Sandpit/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1100, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

This is the code around the mentioned lines:

```
for p in PROPERTIES:

    for x in range(0,100000,25000):
        y = get_sc_df(p,"2021-12-01","2022-12-01",x)
        if len(y) < 25000:
            break
        else:
            continue
```

I'd be grateful for any advice on how to correct this. Thanks in advance.

Mark

ps whole code in picture format below as i'm not allowed to have more code than text

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does `get_sc_df` do?

Comment: Heya, it gets site url, start date, end date and start row

Comment: HI Mark, can you share more of the code you are using? Where are you running the code? Has it ever completed successfully?

Comment: Hi @benp i've added in picture format above if thats ok as i'm not allowed to more code than text. I've running the code on my mac at home. It's never worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Script was timing out because of the size of the dataset required.